# regex to allow all characters except space and slash

Tags: regex, vba, string, ms-access

I have to restrict the user to enter string with any space or any backslashes. Rest all characters shoul be allowed. I tried earlier with below string for regex.

Please correct or help me with a new regular expression to help me with the same. I am doing this in access - vba

`[^0-9a-zA-Z~@#$%^&*()_?<>,.[]{}|-+=]`. 
I am novice in using regex.

Problem solved by this.

```
[\s \\ \/]
```

Comment: Where is the **below string for regex**?

Answer (score 7):

This is regex says "from the beginning of your line, match anything except ' ' or '/' one or more times until the end of the line"

```
/^[^ /]+$/
```

Comment: This still allows every thing. Below is how i useDim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 re.Pattern = "/^[^ /]+$/"
 If re.test(txtIP.Value) Then
               MsgBox "FAIL"
    'End If

Comment: This still fails to identify strings with space or back slash. Plz suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\\ ]*
```

You are using the negate wrong by placing negate in a character class it only accepts characters not listed. 
You also presumably want the * after it so it can be repeated for any number of characters.

Comment: Even this fails to work. I test as with below code

Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 re.Pattern = "/^[^ /]+$/"
 If re.test(txtIP.Value) Then
               MsgBox "FAIL"
    End If

Comment: ^[^\\ ]+$
Testing this regex string on a regex tester works for me (http://regexpal.com/), are you sure you need the start and end of input etc. Otherwise I'd suggest checking your implementation (can't help with vbscript).